# Многопоточный сервер на Qt не обрабатывает 1е собщение

Tags: qt, c++

Начал изучать потоки в Qt. Написал многопоточный сервер. Сами потоки работают, только затык в том, что первое сообщение сервером не ловится. Регистрируется соединение, а при посылке данных пишет, что прислано -123456 байт. Я уже и не знаю что делать.

Сорцы тут: http://pastebin.com/n0rM9Ncs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В методе `void QServerThread::slotReadFromClient()` обнуляйте `m_nNextBlockSize` в начале, а не в конце.